# I can not define the background of my sidebar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, background, sidebar

I have made a sidebar with HTML and CSS. I can style it how I want it except the `background-color`. The background stays transparent and you can see the color of the page.

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0: background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 350px
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">Barber</a>
  <a href="#">Massage</a>
  <a href="#">Nails</a>
</div>
```

Why is this so? I have a Bootstrap CSS could this be the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS is setting `left: 0:` which isn't correct syntax. You'll need to end the line with a semi-colon instead of a colon. If you change it to `left: 0;` your background color will work.

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 350px
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">Barber</a>
  <a href="#">Massage</a>
  <a href="#">Nails</a>
</div>
```

This is one of those things that we've all banged our head against a wall for too long on to realize it was just a simple typo. In this instance it would be very easy to catch with an editor with CSS highlighting. The moment I dropped your code into Codepen it was clear there was a syntax issue.